# Basic ternary circuit to light three LED’s?

Tags: analog, ternary

I need to design a circuit that can light three different LED lights to simulate a traffic signal using two inputs. The first input is either -12v, 0v, + 12v. The second input is always on and it’s just +12v. Thinking as the ternary input as the control the  other as the main power, the following truth table needs to be met. We currently have a circuit working using relays and diodes but I want to try and simplify it (I didn’t design it). Thank you for any help and feed back.

[image: Truth Table]

Comment: What power supply rail voltages do you have available?

Comment: The intent is to eventually replace the main power with a battery in the field. This circuit is going to be used to test equipment that will drive the lights. Currently, I only have two 12v 2A power supplies but I could potentially get a larger one if needed. The goal is the simplest circuit possible to fix in a small rugged case.

Comment: you said that the second input is always on, but your chart shows a different story

Comment: relays are a convenient way to solve this task, designing  it with semiconductors requires more effort.

Comment: I guess what I should have said is during testing, the main power will always be on. I added the “off” states RL simple show all of the configurations

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 4-transistor + 3 diode solution.

V2 +12 D1 on 10mA only

V2 -12 D2 on 10mA only

V2  0V D3 on 10mA only

V1 0V all off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW9aVd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To minimize the current drawn would require another transistor to invert the drive to D3 rather than shunting it.

There might be a simpler approach, this does not quite feel elegant enough.

---

Edit:

Okay, using Jasen's idea of common-base input, the below gets rid of the diodes and still has 4 transistor (5 if you want to avoid the shunt)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLnBXP.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

something like this could do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLFhBc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Appreciate the response, I can't seem to get it working on the breadboard so I have some follow up questions to clarify. 1. Should the Grounds coming off the BJT's be connected to a the same ground? Or do they get connected to the -12 volt return of the main power? Can you add to the schematic the power supplies and grounds?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPYTPC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A couple of opto-isolators can be used to detect polarity and give logic level outputs.*

You'll need a little additional logic for the red lamp.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the assumption that the control signal can source enough current to light the LEDs. I also decided that the LEDs should be off when the input is floating. I then created the circuit shown below.[image]

With a floating input Q1 is off and the current in R4 flows through D1 and D2 and makes the voltage at point A about 4V. When the input is connected to ground, Q1 turns on and LED3 lights and the the voltage at point A drops to about 3V. As the input goes negative LED1 starts to conduct ; at about -10V all the current from R4 flows through LED1. LED3 will be off and the voltage at point A will be around zero volts. When the input goes positive Q1 and LED3 turn off and LED2 turns on; the voltage at point A will stay around 4V. Since the circuit draws current from V+ no matter what, putting a fourth LED in series with R4 would prevent users leaving power on. If you don't have a 3.3V zener D1 and D2 can be LEDs; they can be placed out of sight or used as power on indicators. The resistor values are the ones I used; you may need to scale them to suit your components.

Comment: Is V+ the "Main" signal? I ask because when "Main" is 0 no LEDs should be illuminated even in Control is high.

Answer (score 0):

Nice simple circuit with two relays and two diodes, though I'm sure this is what you currently have.  I don't know that a design with more parts will count as simpler.

[image]